# Make flexbox grid have a horizontal scroll bar on mobile

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, flexbox

I'm trying to figure out how to make a table have a bottom horizontal scroll bar. This is my HTML:

```
<div class="grid-block table">
  <div class="grid-block header"> 
    <div class="grid-block small-2 column"> 
      times 6
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-block row"> 
    <div class="grid-block small-2 column"> 
        times 6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have used this CSS thinking it would fix my problem.

```
.table {
    overflow: auto !important;
    width: 1400px !important;
}
```

I've added the importants at the moment just to make sure these stylings are applied.

I should also point out that every element here is a flex item.

Cheers

Comment: don't really understand your issue. in the fiddle with your code...the horizontal scroll bar appears https://jsfiddle.net/o3pkutL2/

Comment: hmmm must be some foundation crappy CSS messing up

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you get started.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
}
.wrapper .child {
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 50px;
  width: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid coral;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.wrapper .child:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
  <div class="child">9</div>
  <div class="child">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've found out it is something to do with the grid-blocks styling.